# Include generic testcase in codeception

Tags: php, codeception

I have multiple similar websites that I want to test. Here's the current approach:

1. Clone an existing codeception project
2. Adjust the variables
3. Add some additional specific test cases if required

This works just fine, but has one issue. If the general test case changes that means that I have to go into every project and make the changes. So what I would rather see is a way to include a generic top level test case in every project and call it with a parameter.

I tried so with a simple include() statement, but unfortunately this doesn work. And ideas how I can accomplish this?

Here some code of my initial try:

/home/tests/site1/tests/acceptance/isOnlineCept.php

```
include("../1generic_tests/isonline.php");
$I = new AcceptanceTester($scenario);
$I->am('user');
$I->wantTo('see the content of the site');
$I->lookForwardTo('see the homepage');
$I->amOnPage('/');
$I->see("Tech, Geek and Rock'n'Roll");
```

The file I include looks like this

```
$I = new AcceptanceTester($scenario);
$I->am('user');
$I->wantTo('see the content of the site');
$I->lookForwardTo('see the homepage');
$I->amOnPage('/');
$I->see('something else');
```

Unfortunately it fails with this error

```
[PHPUnit_Framework_Exception] Undefined index: class
```

Maybe include is not the right way to do it, but what would be a better way?

Comment: Please provide the code that did not work as we have nothing to go on with how your question is currently stated.

Comment: Added some code

Comment: Why don't you use page objects and declare the function in page objects. Call it with parameters.

Comment: do you have some sample code?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Page Object for this.

Create one Constants.php file using Page Object where you can define all the selectors.

Create one other file where you can keep all common operation going to be performed. E.g. Settings.php file where you can have all methods as per your requirement. you can define it with parameter too.

To access any selector and/or method from declared under page dir can be accessible by using the following line.

> use Page\Constants as ConstantsPage;

To access any selector from any specific file

> FileNamePage::$selectorName;

To access any method, first create the object and then call the method.
E.g.

> $settings = new SettingsPage( $I )
>
> $settings->methodName();

To call the method and/pr selector in the same file.

> self::selectorName;
>
> self::methodName();

Hope this will be helpful.